# How would I rearrange this formula?

Tags: arithmetic

I have a project that I need an equation for, and it looks like this:

$$W = \frac{V}{0.15} \times V$$

I need to rearrange the equation, so that V is the subject.
So, in this situation here:

$$\frac{V}{0.15} \times V = 106.666667$$

I would plug $106,666667$ into $W$ and get $4$ ($V$) as the answer.

I’m not very experienced in math, could someone help out?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax for formatting expressions. I've edited your post to improve the formatting.

Comment: It is not clear to me:Do you mean $$W=\frac{V^2}{0.15}$$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W=\frac{V}{0.15} \times V$

$W= \frac{V^2}{0.15}\Rightarrow V^2=0.15\times W$

$V= \pm \sqrt{0.15\times W}$

Plugging your values

$V = \pm\sqrt{0.15\times106666667}$
$V= \pm\sqrt{16000000.05}$

$\therefore \boxed{V = \pm4000.000}$

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To obtain $V$ as the subject, you have  $W = \frac{V^2}{0.15}$ which gives $V^2 = \frac{W}{0.15}$ and finally $V = \pm \sqrt{\frac{W}{0.15}}$.

Comment: It must be $$V=\pm\sqrt{\frac{W}{0.15}}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Ah, you're right, my mistake. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would write $$V=\pm\frac{\sqrt{15W}}{10}$$